# React. components are not rendered in the order of state change

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

In react, assume I have Input component with prop name = A, B, C.
they are rendered in the order

```
render() {
   return(
      <Input name="A" />
      <Input name="B" />
      <Input name="C" />
   );
}
```

then I change the state of ***C*** and ***A*** in the order first ***C*** then ***A.***
component ***A*** and ***C*** re rendered in the order first ***A*** then ***C***.  they are not rendered in the order of state change(***C*** then ***A***)

See the code snippet given below.
I found the out put as

> set state of C
>
> set state of B
>
> set state of A
>
> Render of A
>
> Render of B
>
> Render of C
>
> ```js
> class Input extends React.Component {
>   
>   
>  componentWillMount() {
>    this.props.addInput(this);
>  }
>   
>   state = {
>    error: false
>    }
>    
>    check() {
>    console.log("set state of", this.props.name)
>     this.setState({
>       error: true
>     })
>    }
>
>   render() {
>    console.log("Render of", this.props.name)
>     return (
>       <input   />
>     );
>   }
> }
> class Hello extends React.Component {
>   
>   constructor(props) {
>   super(props);
>    this.inputs = {};
> }
>
>    addInput(component) {
>       this.inputs[component.props.name] = component;
>       console.log(this.inputs);
>     }
>    
>    checkAll() {
>    const inputs = this.inputs;
>    Object.keys(inputs).reverse().forEach(name => {
>      inputs[name].check()
>     });
>    }
>  
>   render() {
>     return (
>      <div>
>         <Input addInput={(c) => this.addInput(c)} name="A"/>
>         <Input addInput={(c) => this.addInput(c)} name="B"/>
>         <Input addInput={(c) => this.addInput(c)} name="C"/>
>         <button onClick={() => this.checkAll()}>click here</button>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <Hello initialName="World"/>,
>   document.getElementById('container')
> );
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
> <div id="container">
>     <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
> </div>
> ```

Comment: You have to include relevant code parts to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi I just want to know about the order of rendering of react components.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko code snippet added please check

Answer (score 1):

This is how JSX is supposed to work by default.

If you want to render components in an order of last state change, you'll have to put all your components either into an array or have a collection of `componentName: componentInstance`, also having a collection [or an array] of `componentName: lastUpdated` (or array item form `{ componentName: string, lastUpdated: Date }`) in which you can modify each component's `lastUpdated` value and then sort your `componentName: componentInstance` collection or array by the date values.

Then just `.map` in the JSX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please check the updated code.